# Can't pass spec test because of created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm testing 'get' method and getting error:

expected:

> [{\"user_id\":11,\"user_first_name\":\"bob\",\"user_last_name\":\"marley\",\"user_picture\":\"/images/missing.png\",\"id\":2,\"text\":\"my
>   third review\",\"date\":\"2013-12-27T09:08:06.364Z\"}]

got:

> [{\"user_id\":11,\"user_first_name\":\"bob\",\"user_last_name\":\"marley\",\"user_picture\":\"/images/missing.png\",\"id\":2,\"text\":\"my
>   third review\",\"date\":\"2013-12-27T09:08:06.000Z\"}]

what the hell? Why last numbers are different while all other fields are equal?

```
it "should return reviews for user" do
    review = Review.create(reviewer_id: @user.id, user_id: @user2.id, text: 'my third review')
    get 'get_reviews_for_user', user_id: @user2.id
    expect(response).to be_success
    json = JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(json['reviews'].to_json).to eq([{user_id: @user.id, 
                                            user_first_name: @user.first_name, 
                                            user_last_name: @user.last_name,
                                            user_picture: @user.picture.url(:thumb),
                                            id: review.id,
                                            text: review.text,
                                            date: review.created_at
                                            }].to_json)
  end
```

In controller:

```
def get_reviews_for_user
    user = User.where(id: params[:user_id]).first
    return render json: {success: false} if user.nil?
    reviews = []
    Review.where(user_id: user.id).each do |review|
      reviewer = review.reviewer
      reviews << {user_id: reviewer.id, 
                  user_first_name: reviewer.first_name, 
                  user_last_name: reviewer.last_name,
                  user_picture: reviewer.picture.url(:thumb),
                  id: review.id,
                  text: review.text,
                  date: review.created_at}
    end
    render json: { success: true, reviews: reviews }
  end
```

Comment: Please, add the code for your `get_reviews_for_user` action from your controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The times are different because the milliseconds are truncated when the time is translated into JSON.

Comment: Ok, looks like you are right :) But why sometimes 'got' and sometimes 'expected' time is getting trunked? Not 'got' always.. Magic

Comment: If "got" is always obtained through JSON, I can't explain why it wouldn't always be truncated. Expected could be truncated if the value was created as a result of saving JSON and, of course, there is a 1/1000th chance it could have 0 milliseconds naturally.

Comment: One value is always 000 when second could be any number. I have another test, where answer is getting as JSON too and comparison is the same, but there is correct 'got' number and 000 in expected.

Comment: With the knowledge that JSON truncates, I would suggest posing your "counter example" as a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to freeze the time to a give value like this : `Timecop.freeze(Time.now)`.

You can also use a stub like this (in you test) :

```
allow(Review).to receive(:where).with(user_id: @user.id).and_return([review])
allow(review).to receive(:created_at).and_return(Time.now)
```